# What data structure to choose, to implement circle with cuts

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, geometry

I cannot figure out what data structure will be the best for this type of the problem:

I have a circle. It can have cuts at different positions(angle). Segments between cuts have color(say red or black). If there are no cuts all circle has one color.

What operations do I need on it?

[1] Change color of the segment.

[2] Add cut at some angle.

[3] For a given angle tell which segment it belongs.

[4] Join consecutive segments of the same color.

Right now I have class for a Segment storing angles of its ends and color.
And ArrayList to work with it.

Problems that I have:

[1]I want something faster than ArrayList. (TreeSet? something else?)

[2]I am treating circle without cuts as a special case. (two fake cuts at 0 and 0)

[3]I am treating Segments containing 0 angle as special case. Say Segments (7pi/8, pi/8) and (pi/8, 7pi/8) require different approach and enormous amount of if conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this in Java is not to use a data structure, but to create your own class.  EG: a `SegmentedCircle` class.  Give it the API you wish it had and then implement that as behavior.  It'll probably delegate to other classes named `Segment` or `Cut` and may have a list of these.

It's usually a safe bet to get your API right/convenient first, then worry about performance second (and only if it's actually needed).  In other words, don't pre-optimize.

Since you've told me that you need faster Adds and Removes, the right tool for the job may be a `HashSet`.  [From its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)

Note: You need to make sure you implement `equals` and `hashcode` correctly on your classes for this to work propertly.

Comment: I have working program, which uses my own class based on the 'ArrayList<Segment>', but! I use it for Monte Carlo simulations of some Magnetic system (and desired accuracy requires enormous amount of iterations). So performance is crucial(Memory usage is not).

Right now profiler says that most time consuming parts are:

"index" function that is finding what segment some given angle belongs (I keep Segments in order and use binary search)

"add" - adds Segment on a given position.

"remove" - removes Segment from the ArrayList.